# Returning to work after long term disability

Tags: resume, employment-gaps, disability

Here is my situation I have been out of work for nearly 12 years (currently on Social Security Disability Benefits). My previous job title was Senior System Analyst for a major company (I got disabled while working there). I feel that I am ready to return to work but I am afraid that even if I get into the ticket to work program I may not be able to get back in my previous field. I spoke with a representative that issues these tickets and they told me that it should be ok as long as I upgrade my certification/skills.

So as of today I have upgraded my certifications so I am current with new technologies but 12 years is a long time and I do not want to be retrain in a different field since this is what I am really good at.

My questions are, would I be employable after I have upgraded my certifications? How do I justify the huge gab of unemployment on my Resume?  Any word of advice would be super, thank you and God bless.

Comment: Go in and own the room with your confidence and abilities and they wont care what you have been doing.

Comment: You have the relevant qualifications, don't worry about it, you won't get as high a position as you held, but you'll get one and due to your age you'll be on the fast track once you have a job if you are competent and professional and have a good attitude. Ageism works beneficially sometimes.

Answer (score 10):

I was out for almost seven due to a stroke.

Start with volunteer work.  It's a good way to get experience again that demonstrates you've recovered.  From there, it's a long struggle uphill, but you can make it.  You go from volunteer work to a low-level position within a company and either get promoted or move on.

Comment: He could as well start as an intern, chances are that he get a better grasp on how is the industry behaving and how his new co-workers culture is.

Comment: I have been thinking about doing internship but I do not know if I qualify based on my age 46 and because of my extensive previous experience and qualifications.

Comment: @dyeje I'm taking about half of what I could right now, but I'm happy to be working and they're happy to have a discounted hard worker. win-win

Comment: @Tim I'm 47.  GO FOR IT!

Comment: @Richard U, I will!!!!

Comment: The experience gained from working is an asset, especially if you held a responsible position (in any field), assuming your disability didn't get you terminated. You may need to go in at entry level, but this will help you get ahead faster, because you already know how working life goes, and will avoid the common mistakes.

Comment: @Kilisi, I was not terminated but while I was out on Short Term Disability my position was eliminated. I am still listed as an employee with an inactive status then my Disability Status Change to Permanent.

Comment: Well, that's good, should be no issues. Don't worry about the age, you can't change that, I changed industries a few times, I found that the previous experience with having a job and interacting with people in a working environment was  totally relevant and saw me get ahead very quickly (even though the actual task experience was different) and overtake people much younger and possibly more talented.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way of knowing if you are employable in your previous field, I don't know what the job market for your old field looks like. If there is a very low unemployment in it, and high demand, it's certainly possible.

Make sure to be up front about the gap in employment and why they should consider you a potential reliable employee today.  Something like: "I lost my sight in 2004, and became disabled. Since then I have worked hard to learn to navigate the world and function as a vision-impaired person and took the time to upgrade my certificates and skills. While losing my sight was challenging at first, I am now in a place where I have a lot I can contribute to a company."

Comment: My understanding is that I should not add in my Resume anything about my disability even if I am feeling better now because I would be a liability.
I have worked very hard upgrading my Microsoft Certification which has taking me about a six months (Not Easy). My previous certifications are (A+), (CNA), (MCP+I), (MCSE) and now Microsoft Certified System Administrator (MCSA). Plus I have about 13 of years of previous experience in the IT field and the market looks very good. I hope this information may help me move forward even if I have a huge gap of unemployment.

Comment: @Tim I actually got a job because I mentioned mine.  They were so impressed that I came back from nothing that I got the job.  Don't rule any possibility out.  You did it before and you can do it again.

Comment: @Richard U, did you mention it on your Resume or in your interview?

Comment: @Tim On the interview, I mentioned it as part of the "Why should we hire you" question.  I said because I'm tough and I get the job done.  I have come back from a stroke where my doctors said I would never work again.  There is nothing I could face on this job that would be harder than my recovery.

Comment: @Richard U, How did you justify the gab period on your resume? I had been told to add the following: Wanted/needed time off for personal reasons, during my unemployment period. If they ask of course I will be honest about it.

Comment: @Tim "Family medical problem".  Then I explained that it was me on the interview.

Comment: @Tim you're right, don't put it on your resume, but be prepared to be asked about it in the interview process.